# jQuery DataTable 'push' undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to make a daterange picker work for my datatable and I'm receiving an error from this code. What can I do to fix the push error? From what I read, the most common fix is adding a document.ready call around your code. But I am still receiving the error. It's currently not working so I am hoping this fixes my issue. How do I fix this?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2), <anonymous>:77:35)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
at Ha (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
at e.fn.init.append (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
at e.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
at Y (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
at e.fn.init.html (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
at Object.success (apps.js:732)
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                if (dd<10)
                dd = '0'+dd;

                if (mm<10)
                mm = '0'+mm;

                today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

                if ($('#min').val() != '' || $('#max').val() != '') {
                var iMin_temp = $('#min').val();
                if (iMin_temp == '') {
                  iMin_temp = '01/01/1980';
                }

                var iMax_temp = $('#max').val();
                if (iMax_temp == '') {
                  iMax_temp = today;
                }

                var arr_min = iMin_temp.split("/");
                var arr_max = iMax_temp.split("/");
                var arr_date = aData[1].split("/");

                    var iMin = new Date(arr_min[2], arr_min[0], arr_min[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
                var iMax = new Date(arr_max[2], arr_max[0], arr_max[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);
                var iDate = new Date(arr_date[2], arr_date[0], arr_date[1], 0, 0, 0, 0);

                if ( iMin == "" && iMax == "" )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ( iMin == "" && iDate < iMax )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ( iMin <= iDate && "" == iMax )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if ( iMin <= iDate && iDate <= iMax )
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
                }
            }
        );


    $(function() {
        $( "#min" ).datepicker();
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#max" ).datepicker();
    });

    var oTable=$('#data-table').dataTable();

    /* Add event listeners to the two date-range filtering inputs */

$('#min').change( function() { oTable.draw( false ); } );
    $('#max').change( function() { oTable.draw( false ); } );
});
```

Comment: `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.` is not an array, so you can't apply a push on it

Comment: So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: try initialize the table first ... move this `var oTable=$('#data-table').dataTable();` before the `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(...`

Comment: It didn't do anything for me D: